# IONIC2/Angular2 ngOnChange doesn't work

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-directives, ngonchanges

I'm new to Angular2 and I've been struggling for a while with this problem and have found no solution to it online.

**[on ionic2!]**

I want to use ngOnChanges() so i can detect changes to **zonaid**:

**estados.html:**

```
<ion-item>
       <ion-label color="branco">Zonas</ion-label>


              <ion-select *ngIf="isTrue2" [(ngModel)]=zonaid>
                 <ion-option value={{bicho.zonas}} *ngFor="let bicho of idespecie">
                    {{bicho.zonas}}
                 </ion-option>
             </ion-select>


              <ion-select *ngIf="!isTrue2" [(ngModel)]="zonaid">
                 <ion-option value={{item.id}} *ngFor="let item of itemsZon" >
                    {{item.codigo}}
                 </ion-option>

              </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
```

**idespecie** and **itemsZon** are parts of .json files

**estados.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IpmaBivService} from '../../app/services/ipmabiv.service'
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-estados',
  templateUrl: 'estados.html'
})
export class EstadosPage {
   itemsZon: any;
   itemsEsp: any;
   zonaEscolhida: any;

   @Input()
   zonaid: string;


   idzona: '';
   idespecie: any[];

   isTrue1:boolean = false;
   isTrue2:boolean = false;
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private ipmaBivService:IpmaBivService) {
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
     console.log('ngOnChanges ran');
     if(this.zonaid != ''){
        this.isTrue1 = true;
        this.getJsonZonas(this.zonaid);
     }
     if(this.especie != ''){
        this.isTrue2 = true;
        this.getJsonEspecies(this.especie);
     }
 }

}
  ngOnInit(){
     this.getDataZonas('zonas')
     this.getDataEspecies('especies')
   //   this.getData('especies')
 }
 }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { EstadosPage } from '../pages/estados/estados';
import { OutrosPage } from '../pages/estados/outros';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    EstadosPage,
    OutrosPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    OutrosPage,
    EstadosPage

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Everything is happening in the same component (ionic page).

My goal is just to be able to run a method whenever **zonaid** changes. If you think there is a better way than goin through ngOnChanges, pls let me know

Thanks!

Comment: What I see at the first sight - your class does not implement interfaces properly. Use 'implements' keyword when you define the class. For example: "class MyComponent implements OnInit". Then all the interfaces should work as you expect.

Comment: Interfaces are lost after compilation has completed. They only assist (in typescript) in more understandable code, thats the only benefit.

Comment: @plvice thank you for your answer, still the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember to always add qoutes, change `[(ngModel)]=zonaid` to `[(ngModel)]="zonaid"`

Anyway, as an answer try this:

Change `<ion-select *ngIf="isTrue2" [(ngModel)]=zonaid>`

to

`<ion-select *ngIf="isTrue2" [ngModel]="zonaid"
 (ngModelChange)="runYourFunction($event)">`

Remember to create a public `runYourFunction(event) {}` in your code.

With this you'll be data binding from the component to the view, and whenever the view changes, you'll run the function `runYourFunction`.

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for your answer. Still, runYourFunction(event) { console.log('runYourFunction ran'); } does not print to the console when i select one of the options. I've updated the html as you suggested as well.

Answer (score 1):

try `export class EstadosPage implements OnChanges {`

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 1):

ngOnChanges is not required. Angular will automatically update the selected value with binding. Dark Neuron answer will work but code need to change from  `[ngModel]="zonaid"` to `[(ngModel)]="zonaid"`. You can also find my [working version of ionic dropdown here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio)

Your HTML should look like this.

```
<ion-item>
       <ion-label color="branco">Zonas</ion-label>
              <ion-select *ngIf="isTrue2" [(ngModel)]="zonaid" (ngModelChange)="zonaiChanged()">
                 <ion-option value={{bicho.zonas}} *ngFor="let bicho of idespecie">
                    {{bicho.zonas}}
                 </ion-option>
             </ion-select>


              <ion-select *ngIf="!isTrue2" [(ngModel)]="zonaid" (ngModelChange)="zonaiChanged()">
                 <ion-option value={{item.id}} *ngFor="let item of itemsZon" >
                    {{item.codigo}}
                 </ion-option>

              </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
```

In TS file call zonaiChanged to do something on dropdown change

```
zonaiChanged(){
alert(this.zonaid);
}
```

Comment: your version of the ionic dropdown helped a lot, dhanyawad bhaiya

Comment: Glad it helped :)